How to put json string data with incremental keys as IDs into data class
I have a piece of json string from my ktor response.body
val jsonString = """ {
          "0": {
            "title": 111,
            "artist": "AAA",
            "album": "ZZZ"
          },
          "1": {
            "title": 222,
            "artist": "BBB",
            "album": "YYY"
          },
          "2": {
            "title": 333,
            "artist": "CCC",
            "album": "XXX"
          }
}""".trimIndent()

I am trying to create a data class object so that I can load this string into it. But the error I get is that the keys from my data class is not found - so the string object can't be mapped to the data class.
What I've tried:
@Serializable
data class DataClassWithKeys(
    val items: Map<Int, Item>
) {
    @Serializable
    data class Item(
        val title: Int,
        val artist: String,
        val album: String,
    )
}

val dataClassWithMap = Json.decodeFromString<DataClassWithKeys>(jsonString)


The problem is that your JSON doesn't contain an items property. It is actually just a Map<Int, Item>, not a DataClassWithKeys.
Use this instead:
val map = Json.decodeFromString<Map<Int, DataClassWithKeys.Item>>(jsonString)
val dataClassWithMap = DataClassWithKeys(map)

